# TravisCI not failing even though unit tests fail

Tags: javascript, github, gruntjs, travis-ci, qunit

I'm testing my GitHub-integrated Travis CI/Grunt build and it seems it's not failing even when my tests fail.

You can see [here](https://travis-ci.org/jonbri/testtravis) that my two jobs "jshint" and "qunit" are failing:

```
Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Task "qunit:files" failed. Used --force, continuing.
```

but the Travis CI build still "passed":

```
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

In my [`package.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonbri/testtravis/master/package.json) I specified in `scripts` to run `grunt qunit`:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "grunt qunit"
}
```

and in my [`Gruntfile.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonbri/testtravis/master/Gruntfile.js) I registered a `test` task:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint','qunit']);
```

How do I get my Travis CI build to fail when my linting or unit testing fails?

Comment: I guess because they are "Warnings" they don't return a non-zero exit code? Try something akin to `-Werror` or maybe hack the return code via `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by removing the `--force` from [your](https://git.io/vat1j) `travis.yml`

This is what manual says:

> --force, -f
>
> A way to force your way past warnings. Want a suggestion? Don't use
>   this option, fix your code.